# Why in Flutter after adding icon. I am getting Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> .png: Error: The file name must end with .xml

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter.

after adding lunch icon.

as png file. under root icon folder.

I am getting :

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\flutter\trex\android\app\src\main\res\icon\TrexIcon.png: Error: The file name must end with .xml
```

I have added

```
# flutter_icons:
#   image_path: "icon/TrexIcon.png" 
#   android: true
#   ios: false
```

as well.

Any reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong use.
Please read document for use local image on app:
[adding asset and images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)

If you want use [flutter_icons package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_icons/install) please read to document.